# Viewing 'Last Run Date' for a Test Case in Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: mtm, mstest

I am looking to use Microsoft Test Manager to manage regression testing of our product.

One fairly key missing feature though as far as I can tell is that there is no way to see when a test case in the library/database was last run, when viewing a number of test cases from a query, i.e.

**| Test Title** ________________ **| Last Run Date |**

| Test Something Works______ | 05-04-2016 | 
| Test Something Else Works__ | 01-01-2016 |

I know I can view this History when viewing an individual Test Case within a plan, but I want to see this at a multi test case level, to drive whether or not I add that test to my plan for this round of regression testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because test runs are not directly associated to Test Cases.

Each test case is associated with at least one configuration (if you don't assign one, there's a generic default). The pair [Test Case, Test Configuration] forms a Test Point, and each run is associated to the test point.

MTM queries work on Work Items, and can only return data associated with things that are types of Work Items. For testers, that's Test Cases and Test Suites (if your version of MTM is recent enough). Test Points and Test Runs aren't queryable through that engine: you need to use the Team Foundation Server reporting engine to retrieve test run information linked to lists of test cases.

The reason you need to open the test case to review the results, is that once the test case is open, the test points of that test case are accessible, so that links in the test results.